# Where is IsHandleCreate property in WPF controls library?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

In my C# WinForms application I would check IsHandleCreated on controls before executing certain operations, especially those from code that was the target of an Invoke call.  I don't see that property in WPF (using a TextBlock control currently).  What is the equivalent property or operation in WPF to make sure a control has a handle before accessing it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why do you need the handle in the WPF world?

Comment: You may be looking for the [Loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to invoke the UI thread from an asynchronous method, you'll have to use

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher
```

As for making sure the control has a handle before accessing it... you'll need to use this snippet:

```
HwndSource hwnd = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(textBox1);
```

With textBox1 being the name/id of your wpf control.

Comment: Please note that `HwndSource.FromVisual` returns the same HwndSource (and hence the same window handle) for all controls in a WPF window, namely that of the window that contains the controls. The reason is that controls in WPF are not seperate windows, as they usually are in WinForms.

Comment: @Clemens Does that mean I don't have to worry about checking to see if a control's window handle is valid (has been created) when doing operations across threads like I do with a WinForms app?

Comment: As said before, a WPF control does not have a window handle of its own. Hence you can't check for one. Calls that update the UI from another thread have to be done via the Dispatcher.